# How is data from tf.data generated and passed to the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In the book Hands-On ML with Scikit-Learn, Tensorflow and Keras, the author explains using the Data API to manipulate, transform and pass data to the model efficiently, he writes the following function:

```
def csv_reader(filepaths, batch_size=32):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filepaths)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda filepath:
    tf.data.TextLineDataset(filepath).skip(1), cycle_length=5)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).repeat(1)
    return dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

Then : `train_set = csv_reader_dataset(train_filepaths)`

and: `model.fit(train_set, epochs=10)`

What I don't understand is the part where he creates the actual train_set from the function, isn't that way he only has one batch of data? He says that we create a training set once and don't need to repeat it as it will be taken care of by Keras but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

A `tf.data.Dataset` is like a blueprint for how to get your data. To use a dataset to read data, you create an iterator over the dataset. The same dataset can be used to create multiple iterators, which will each iterate over the whole dataset. So Keras just needs one dataset, then can use the dataset to iterate over your data multiple times.